# Display currency selected by user on top

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, multicurrency

please visit [link](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/) , on top left you can see "currency" , once we mouse-over  we can see
list of store view names and currency assigned to each store.

what i want is if user select "Euro" ,

it should display the **currency : [€]** on top,

for US Dollar, it should display **currency : [$]**

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <ul id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Currency') ?>" class="dropDownMenu">
        <li><a href=""><?php echo $this->__('Currency') ?></a>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
                <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' class="selected"' : '' ?>
                <li <?php echo $_selected ?>>
                <a href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this :

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <ul id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Currency') ?>" class="dropDownMenu">
        <li><a href=""><?php echo $this->__('Currency') ?></a>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
                <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' class="selected"' : '' ?>
                <li <?php echo $_selected ?>>
                <a href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

WITH :

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<?php
$lis = "";
$selCurrency = $this->__('Currency');
foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang):
    if($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()){
        //This line will show SYMBOL only
        //$selCurrency = "[".Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol()."]";

        //This line will show FULLNAME
        $selCurrency = $this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName());
    }
    $lis .= '<li><a href="'.$_lang->getCurrentUrl().'">'.$this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()).'</a></li>';
endforeach;
?>
<div class="form-language">
    <ul id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Currency') ?>" class="dropDownMenu">
        <li><a href=""><?php echo $selCurrency ?></a>
        <ul>
            <?php echo $lis ?>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: still its not displaying.

Comment: check Updated answer

Comment: Nice ,it worked fine. can you please help me to display currency name also, like " US dollar : $" instead of only "$"

Comment: Check answer with COMMENTS, Solved the TYPO

Comment: working, one last thing :-) , but currency text is not displaying in left.

Comment: what do you mean buy `not displaying in left` ?

Comment: means , i want to display "currency" text in left means : `currency : Indian Rupess [INR ]`

Comment: Replace `$selCurrency = $this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName());` with `$selCurrency = 'currency : '.$this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName());`

Answer (score 1):

Try is code. It may help you

```
<?php if($this->getCurrencyCount() > 1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <label for="custom-currency-selector"><?php echo $this->__('Your Currency:') ?></label>
    <select onchange="window.location.href=this.value" name="custom-currency-selector" id="custom-currency-selector">
        <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code)?>"
            <?php if($_code == $this->getCurrentCurrencyCode()): ?>
                selected="SELECTED"
            <?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $_code ?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: i replaced your code, but after that it didt displayed anything,

Comment: in which file you have placed this code

Comment: i replaced in same file that i posted code in question. `app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/page/switch/languages.phtml`

Comment: Try it like this http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/

Comment: sure,  i will try this & let you know.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
    <div class="form-language">
        <ul id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Currency') ?>" class="dropDownMenu">
            <li><a href=""><?php echo $this->__('Currency') ?></a>
            <ul>
                <?php 
                $select="";
                $other="";
                foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>

                    <?php if($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) { $select='<li class="selected">
                    <a href="'.$_lang->getCurrentUrl().'">'.$this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()).'</a>
                    </li>'; } else {
                        $other .='<li >
                    <a href="'.$_lang->getCurrentUrl().'">'.$this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()).'</a>
                    </li>';
                    }
                 endforeach; echo $select; echo $other; ?>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: sorry its displyed blank page now.

Comment: update the code

Comment: now blank page not displaying. but its not working for me.

Comment: can you tell what is not working it is not showing the selected first?

Comment: yes, it not showing the selected currency on top.

Comment: updated the code check and feedback me

Comment: sorry, it didt worked, may be i am doing something wrong .thanks for your support. I  got solution.